# MyTouch 3G Slide screen went Blank?

Tags: backup, factory-reset, htc-mytouch-3g-slide

I have contacted Tmobile and they are going to be resending me a replacement.  But I am wondering what all is stored on my phone that I am losing access to?  And is there potential for when I send it back to Tmobile that they will be able to access my private calendar, files, emails, etc?  I can't do a reset of any kind because it won't respond to anything.  But I hate that I had text messages on there saved with information for future reference and my reminders from my calendar my alarm, etc are all still working because I'm getting the vibrations and music to alert me of these, I just can't view them.

This seems like a common problem with the 3G Slide, as they didn't even hardly question me about a replacement, just told me to try reset it, when it wouldn't reset they said they'd send me a new one.

Basically just wondering if there is any possible way to access my info on  my old phone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you install the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) on your computer, you can connect the phone via USB and use the `adb` tool to perform a factory reset on your phone.  That will erase all your data.  You can also use `adb` to retrieve files and data before doing the wipe.

To retrieve files, type the following at the command prompt / terminal on your computer (make sure it's running in the directory where you have the SDK):

`./adb pull phone-file backup-file`

For example,

`./adb pull /sdcard/DCIM/myphoto.jpg C:\backups\myphoto.jpg`

And to wipe the phone:

`./adb wipe data`

You might need to try some variants of that, and on some phones you will unfortunately need to be rooted.

More info on adb: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

**Edit:** There's a better way to do a factory reset!  It's harder without a screen, but not impossible.

1. Power the device off. If the device is unresponsive and does not turn off, remove the battery and then re-insert it.
2. Press and hold the Home key and the red End key for 30 seconds, the release.
3. Wait a few seconds, then press the Home key and the Power key again.
4. Wait 30 seconds, then press Volume Down twice.  Click the Power button once.
5. Give the phone a few minutes to do the factory reset.

With-screen instructions are [here](http://community.htc.com/na/htc-forums/android/f/18/t/131.aspx).

Comment: Note also, some guides say VolDown + Power for step 3 and to skip step 4.  Perhaps try both, since you don't know what will succeed if you have no screen :(

Answer (score 0):

Your personal information like Contacts, Tasks and all this kind of stuff are synced automatically with your Google account by default and when you login at your new phone all this information will get pushed into your new device.

I don't know, but maybe T-Mobile will transfer your files from the defective unit to the working one, but I'm not sure about this possibility. I suggest you to ask them if they can transfer your files from the old to the new one, but remember that your private stuff like Contacts will get synced OTA.